# How to change the color of text dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

I want "Password Matched" in Green Color & "Password Don't Match" in Red Color

I'm Trying these lines of codes but not happening.
But the main problem is Both "Password Matched" & "Password Don't Match" is coming.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkPasswordMatch() {
var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
var confirmPassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword").val();

if (password == confirmPassword)
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Password Matched");
else
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch2").html("Passwords Don't Match.");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#txtConfirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
}); 
</script>
```

And this is my HTML Code

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required" name="txtNewPassword" id="txtNewPassword">
<br />
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="required" name="txtConfirmPassword" id="txtConfirmPassword" onChange="checkPasswordMatch();">
<div id="divCheckPasswordMatch2" style="color:red">
<div id="divCheckPasswordMatch" style="color:green">
```

Comment: `if (password = confirmPassword)` is wrong. That should be == not =. There are a bunch of other things wrong here too like if my passwords don't match, then I try again and they do, both messages will be displayed.

Comment: or even better: `if (password === confirmPassword) {`

Comment: `=` is not used for comparisons. Also always explain what happens and what should happen rather than being vague.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console? What debugging have you done? Are you including jQuery?

Comment: You're not closing your `div`s, so it may be that your `divCheckPasswordMatch` is nested under your `divCheckPasswordMatch2` and is therefore wiped out if the passwords don't match.

Comment: It is working only for 1 time.

If I type "1" and in confirm Password I typed "1" then only for first time its showing it in green color. But when i tried again its not happening.

Comment: Both the div is coming. I want only one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<div>`'s in your html need to be closed.  Your browser does not know how to structure broken html, so it will likely render your html as nested `<div>`'s like this:

```
<div id="divCheckPasswordMatch2" style="color:red">
   <div id="divCheckPasswordMatch" style="color:green">
   </div>
</div>
```

This means that when you replace the html with the javascript line:

```
$("#divCheckPasswordMatch2").html("Passwords Don't Match.");
```

That the browser removes the other `<div>` to put in the string `"Passwords Don't Match"`. The result is:

```
<div id="divCheckPasswordMatch2" style="color:red">
   <!-- This other div is removed -->
   Passwords don't match
</div>
```

Now, any attempt to replace the text on `#divCheckPasswordMatch` will fail, because that element does not exist any more.

Here is how to fix that problem:  **add closing tags**

```
<div id="divCheckPasswordMatch2" style="color:red"></div>
<div id="divCheckPasswordMatch" style="color:green"></div>
```

By adding closing tags, you are telling the browser where to end your block, and you are telling the browser that the blocks are next to each-other and not containing each other.  With this change, you will now be able to add and remove text freely to both div's and it will never affect the other div.

Now, let us take this fix a little farther.

@dman2306 correctly pointed out that your code will show both the error message and the success message as written. Let's fix that by using just one div and changing the class.

Use the following:

```js
//HTML5 does not require type tags on your script blocks
    function checkPasswordMatch() {
        var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
        var confirmPassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword").val();
        var div = $( "#messageBlock" );
    
        if (password == confirmPassword){
            $(div).removeClass( "bad_password" );
            if( password == "" && confirmPassword == "" ){
                /* 
                    We do not delete the div. 
                    We set the html content to 
                    an empty string. This way 
                    we can use the DIV again in the future */
                $(div).html(""); 
            }else{
                $(div).html("Password Matched");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $(div).html("Passwords Don't Match.");
            $(div).addClass("bad_password");
        }
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtConfirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
    });
```

```css
#messageBlock { color: green; }
    #messageBlock.bad_password { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Example</h1>
<p>Please enter passwords to check the behavior of the message div</p>
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required" name="txtNewPassword" id="txtNewPassword">
    <br />
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="required" name="txtConfirmPassword" id="txtConfirmPassword" onChange="checkPasswordMatch();">
    <div id="messageBlock"><!-- this is where ALL messages appear, and the color is based on the class name --></div>
```

Run the code above to see a live example of the new code.

This code has the following benefits:

1. By using a single message div, you show only one message at a time. All new messages replace the preceding message.
2. The color is not hard-coded into the element, so you can change the look of your page just by changing your css, which now sits in a `<style>` element.
3. Your javascript becomes a little more simple, you only need to worry about adding the right message and then adding or removing a single class name.  The default text color is green, and with the class name `bad_password`, the text color changes to red.

You can still make several improvements on this design, but I have made recommendations based on your submission so that you can grow and improve as a coder. Keep up the good work and soon you will be building amazing things!

Comment: Thank you, it's working fine. But if the password field remains blank then that message should not be shown. For that, I did this coding,

`if (password == empty){
        
        $(div).remove;
        
        }
`

But it's not working

Comment: You don't want to remove your message div, because it prevents you from using it again in the future.  You can create and add divs dynamically, but it is much easier to use `if( password == empty ){ $(div).innerHTML = ""; }`  It removes the text and makes the div empty.

Comment: If you want the DIV to no longer take up space on the screen (perhaps you have a button that you want to move up when the div is empty), then you can add the line `$(div).hidden = true;`  This is similar to `$(div).visible = false`, except the `hidden` property also collapses the div's dimensions so it takes up zero space.  The visible property only controls whether it is visible or not.

Comment: By using these properties, you never have to worry about creating, inserting, altering and removing divs.  You only need to change the div that is already there.

Comment: I tried this codes but it's not working, May be i am doing something wrong.. :( Can you please give us a code snippet ?

Comment: Vivek, I have just updated my snippet in my answer to include the case of blank passwords. Please see my edits there.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below to have persistent color:

```
if (password == confirmPassword)
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Password Matched").css("color", "green");
else
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch2").html("Passwords Don't Match.").css("color", "red");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this, I would only have one div for the message and then style it accordingly.  And then I would clear the message if a new password is being typed.

```
<style>
    .green {
        color: green;
    }
    .red {
        color: red;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkPasswordMatch() {
        var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
        var confirmPassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword").val();

        if (password == confirmPassword) {
            $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").text("Password Matched");
            $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").css("color", "green");
        }
        else {
            $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").text("Passwords Don't Match");
            $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").css("color", "red");

        }
    }

    function clearMessage() {
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").text("");
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtNewPassword").keyup(clearMessage);
        $("#txtConfirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
    }); 
</script>

<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required" name="txtNewPassword" id="txtNewPassword">
<br />
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="required" name="txtConfirmPassword" id="txtConfirmPassword" onChange="checkPasswordMatch();">
<div id="divCheckPasswordMatch"></div>
```